# How to Add Map<String, Object> elements in firebase firestore android using Hashmap? A Store Database

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

With the last improvement in matrices, you can add, update and delete an element but only in matrix.

But for:

```
Map<String, Object> comentarios = new HashMap<>();
```

I probe it and it transforms me a Map to array does not matiene the same type.
Someone know how I should do it?

My code is:

```
final Map<String, Object> nuevoComentario = new HashMap<>();
nuevoComentario.put("comentario", FieldValue.arrayUnion("id5", "Msj add"));
db.collection("Hospedaje").document(documentGetID)
                        .update(nuevoComentario);
```

Comment: Hey Christian. I'm having a really hard time following along with what you're trying to do. Can you add a `println` to the code that shows what the code delivers, and then show the values you'd expect (in the same format)?

Comment: My question is that how to manage comments HashMap? (add, update, remove), I have already been able to add, but I have not been able to modify and delete.

Comment: @Frank I want to do the same as this but using HashMap and not an Array : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202300/how-to-add-update-remove-array-elements-in-firebase-firestore-android-using-hash

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand `FieldValue.arrayUnion` and `FieldValue.arrayRemove` are just for array fields, which HashMap isn't really. 
Try using `db.collection("Hospedaje").document(documentGetID).update("myHashMapField", "key" to /value/);`